# Updating dates in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table that has a column with several dates as follows ?

```
15-JAN-2018 07:18:09
13-JAN-2018 09:09:19
15-JAN-2018 05:29:21
15-JAN-2018 05:30:26
13-JAN-2018 07:23:19
13-JAN-2018 02:30:12
14-JAN-2018 02:30:12
14-JAN-2018 03:30:12
```

Is it possible to convert all these dates to the 12th respecting the hour/ minute, as follows :

```
12-JAN-2018 07:18:09
12-JAN-2018 09:09:19
12-JAN-2018 05:29:21
12-JAN-2018 05:30:26
12-JAN-2018 07:23:19
12-JAN-2018 02:30:12
12-JAN-2018 02:30:12
12-JAN-2018 03:30:12
```

Comment: Apparently all of your times are 24-hour times that happened in the AM?

Comment: Are all the date sin the same month, and are any before the 12th - do they all need to be adjusted to the 12th of their original month whatever their current date, or the 12th of this month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could adjust in day intervals:

```
your_date - numtodsinterval(extract(day from your_date) - 12, 'DAY')
```

Demo:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

with t (dt) as (
  select to_date('15-JAN-2018 07:18:09', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select to_date('13-JAN-2018 09:09:19', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select to_date('15-JAN-2018 05:29:21', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select to_date('15-JAN-2018 05:30:26', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select to_date('13-JAN-2018 07:23:19', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select to_date('13-JAN-2018 02:30:12', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select to_date('14-JAN-2018 02:30:12', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select to_date('14-JAN-2018 03:30:12', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
)
select dt, dt - numtodsinterval(extract(day from dt) - 12, 'DAY')
from t;

DT                  DT-NUMTODSINTERVAL(
------------------- -------------------
2018-01-15 07:18:09 2018-01-12 07:18:09
2018-01-13 09:09:19 2018-01-12 09:09:19
2018-01-15 05:29:21 2018-01-12 05:29:21
2018-01-15 05:30:26 2018-01-12 05:30:26
2018-01-13 07:23:19 2018-01-12 07:23:19
2018-01-13 02:30:12 2018-01-12 02:30:12
2018-01-14 02:30:12 2018-01-12 02:30:12
2018-01-14 03:30:12 2018-01-12 03:30:12
```

The `extract(day from your_date)` gives you the day number, e.g. 13, 14 or 15. Subtracting 12 from that gives you the difference in days between each value and the 12th of the month (always positive in your sample, but could be negative too). The [`numtodsinterval()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/NUMTODSINTERVAL.html) converts that offset into an interval. And that interval is applied to the original value.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well you may need something like this.

Starting data:

```
SQL> select * from dates;

D
-------------------------------------------------
15-JAN-18 12:34:45,000000000
14-JAN-18 12:12:45,000000000
11-JAN-18 12:34:45,000000000
12-JAN-18 12:00:45,000000000
```

Update:

```
SQL> update dates
  2  set d =  d - trunc(d) + date '2018-01-12';

4 rows updated.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from dates;

D
-------------------------------------------------
12-JAN-18 12:34:45,000000000
12-JAN-18 12:12:45,000000000
12-JAN-18 12:34:45,000000000
12-JAN-18 12:00:45,000000000
```

This simply gets the time part of the starting dates and adds it to 2018-01-12 00:00

Answer (score 2):

You can use this concept right here:

```
select sysdate, 
       to_date( '12'||to_char(sysdate,'MMYYYYHH24MISS'), 'DDMMYYYYHH24MISS' )
  from dual;
```

Replace `sysdate` with your field name (in the 2nd selected element) and `dual` with your table name.

This restructures the date by prepending the day of the month that you want.  And since we've defined the format we're passing in as `'MMYYYYHH24MISS'`, prepending that `12` is like hard-coding the `DD` part.

The select statement above demonstrates conceptually what you need to do.  Without knowing your column name and table name, it's hard to construct an exact answer, but I think you'll get the gist of it if you run that statement above exactly as it's written (it's harmless).